# 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I m tryting to make concat networks which are LSTM,LSTM(EMBEDDING),DNN
to solve classification problem

but I got this error.
See the code below:

```
# Shared Feature Extraction Layer
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.layers.merge import concatenate

# define input
visible = Input(shape=(190,1))
visible1 = Input(shape=(3000,1))

# feature extraction
extract1 =  LSTM(50, return_sequences=False)(visible)

extract2 = LSTM(50, return_sequences=False)(visible1)

# merge interpretation
merge = concatenate([extract1, extract2])
# output
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merge)
model = Model(inputs=[visible,visible1], outputs=output)
# summarize layers
print(model.summary())
model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics= 
['accuracy'])  
print("test",data.shape) 
print("test2",data_.shape)
# model.fit([data,data_],  y,  epochs=20, verbose=1)
```

[image]

> but got this error:
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 model.fit([data,data_], y, epochs = 350, batch_size = 64)
>
> /etc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in
>   fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
>   validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
>   sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
>   **kwargs)    1628             sample_weight=sample_weight,    1629             class_weight=class_weight,
>   -> 1630             batch_size=batch_size)    1631         # Prepare validation data.    1632         do_validation = False
>
> /etc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in
>   _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)    1478
>   output_shapes,    1479
>   check_batch_axis=False,
>   -> 1480                                     exception_prefix='target')    1481         sample_weights =
>   _standardize_sample_weights(sample_weight,    1482                                                      self._feed_output_names)
>
> /etc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in
>   _standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
>        74         data = data.values if data.**class**.**name** == 'DataFrame' else data
>        75         data = [data]
>   ---> 76     data = [np.expand_dims(x, 1) if x is not None and x.ndim == 1 else x for x in data]
>        77 
>        78     if len(data) != len(names):
>
> /etc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in
>   (.0)
>        74         data = data.values if data.**class**.**name** == 'DataFrame' else data
>        75         data = [data]
>   ---> 76     data = [np.expand_dims(x, 1) if x is not None and x.ndim == 1 else x for x in data]
>        77 
>        78     if len(data) != len(names):
>
> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'

plz, help me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
visible = Input(shape=(190,1))
visible1 = Input(shape=(3000,1))
model = Model(inputs=[visible,visible1], outputs=output)
```

And you try to run `model.fit([data,data_], y, epochs = 350, batch_size = 64)`. Then, you should have `data_.shape == (*, 3000, 1)`, but you have `data_.shape = (*, 190, 1)`. That won't work.

But the summary shows `(None, 190, 1)`. So i guess you corrected that. Once I made this correction, the network trains properly, I didn't get any errors.

What is the shape of your `y`?